# Storing in PHP arrays or mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column in a mySQL table that is either has a value of 0 or 1 and they refer to "for rent" and "for Sale" respectively. The question is should I put these values' interpretation in mySQL table and do `inner join` or just put them in PHP array?. which one is more efficient in terms of speed and maintenance?

### update:

I am asking which is better:

1) storing values' meaning in DB table and do `inner join`

2) storing values' meaning in PHP array and substitute the values with the meanings after retrieving the data.

in terms of speed and maintenance.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you use a 0 or 1 to show that? Is it to save memory? Why not just store it as a varchar RENT or SALE?

Comment: Or use an ENUM with "rent" and "sale" values?

Comment: I do not want to store the actual words so I have a chance to change them when I need to. "rent" and "sale" are only examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proper database design is a safe bet almost in all cases. Denormalising a database on purpose is something you do in heavy data warehouse applications where there's just no way to make real-time calculations with your 30TB worth of data even if your data is partitioned, and only for specific and well analysed situations.

As soon as you stop storing raw values into your database you're no longer able to use the most basic features your DBMS offers:

- Referential integrity enforcement
- Indexes
- Searches

You're transferring all this responsibility from a native application specially created to manipulate data into an interpreted general purpose language that does not even have direct access to the data vault.

Comment: @Sami, as you see from answers it depends on your amount of data, the type of the relations, in terms of speed probably do it in hard php code, in terms of maintenance of course in the DB. It depends on whuch normalization you want to follow... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization ... well.. it just depends on something :-)

Comment: The data I am talking about is a very small amount like the example above. I thought instead of slowing down the query by using `inner join` I can use PHP arrays for such things. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: The inner join slowdown you fear so much is probably in the range of milliseconds. I'm sure that PHP array manipulation is slower than that.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to add PHP array into mysql, then you convert that into json and add the json value. While getting also get it and reconvert it into array. Use the following functions for that,

```
json_encode($array);
json_decode($json);
```